# Can someone explain Elasticsearch index_time_in_millis?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am testing Elasticsearch performance and need some help on understanding one of stats.
The _stats API for an index shows that indexing took 2014943633 in milliseconds. Then, it’s 559 hours (23 days). How can it be? Should I divide that number with the number of shards, cores, or segments?

The index is with 12 shards, 509 segments.

```
    "indexing" : {
      "index_total" : 1664997009,
      "index_time_in_millis" : 2014943633,
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2014943633ms *looks* plausible when 1,664,997,009 [indexing operations](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/53a67db0508d46c99cbeea1a296c72cea27b7d07/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/shard/IndexingStats.java#L88) were performed.
Quoting from [this GH issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17842#issuecomment-211841034):

> The index time measures how much time was spent in indexing threads. Threads can execute in parallel, so two threads in parallel which take 10ms each would result in 20ms of indexing time.

Comment: Number of threads! Thanks for the helpful answer.